# Ruby on rails. Heroku compile assets timeout when i add unicorn gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, unicorn

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   !     Timed out compiling Ruby app (15 minutes)
   !     See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#time-limit
```

When I delete unicorn gem from gemfile assets:precompile start works... How i can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this seems like a setup issue to me, I'll give you the guides I've been looking at.

The way I would solve this would be to google the error. When I typed in heroku unicorn setup I got this page: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn

**UPDATE:** The error that I was struggling with was an asset compilation issue. That was brought to my attention through using inspect element on my webpage. So I went through a few guides again to make sure the assets pre-complied (can only give the names since I already have two links):

1. Deploying Rails Applications with Unicorn
2. Getting Started with Rails 4.x on Heroku
3. SQLite on Heroku *(I had to update my app from SQLite)*
4. Rails 4 Asset Pipeline on Heroku

### **Otherwise, here's the guide I've been following:**

#### below are some instructions for getting your app onto heroku...

**Heroku specific instructions:**

```
NOTE: everything from below this point will be for getting your app ready for deployment onto Heroku.
```

To enable features such as static asset serving and logging on Heroku add rails_12factor gem to the end of your Gemfile.

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

Specify specific Ruby. At the end of your gemfile add...

```
ruby "2.1.2"
```

### Add Unicorn Webserver to your Gemfile:

Inside your gemfile

```
gem 'unicorn'
```

Then run

```
$ bundle install
```

Now you are ready to configure your app to use Unicorn.

Create a configuration file for Unicorn at config/unicorn.rb:

```
$ touch config/unicorn.rb
```

Add Unicorn specific configuration options In file config/unicorn.rb:

```
worker_processes Integer(ENV["WEB_CONCURRENCY"] || 3)
timeout 15
preload_app true

before_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
    Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT'
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

This default configuration assumes a standard Rails app with Active Record. You should get acquainted with the different options in [the official Unicorn documentation](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/Unicorn/Configurator.html).

Finally you will need to tell Heroku how to run your Rails app by creating a Procfile in the root of your application directory.

### Add a Procfile:

```
touch Procfile
(note: the case is important!)
```

in the Procfile write:

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
```

Set the RACK_ENV to development in your environment and a PORT to connect to. Before pushing to Heroku you’ll want to test with the RACK_ENV set to production since this is the enviroment your Heroku app will run in.

```
$ echo "RACK_ENV=development" >> .env
$ echo "PORT=3000" >> .env
```

You’ll also want to add .env to your .gitignore since this is for local enviroment setup.

```
$ echo ".env" >> .gitignore
$ git add .gitignore
$ git commit -m "add .env to .gitignore"
```

Test your Procfile locally using Foreman:

```
$ gem install foreman
```

You can now start your web server by running

```
$ foreman start
18:24:56 web.1  | I, [2013-03-13T18:24:56.885046 #18793]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:5000 fd=7
18:24:56 web.1  | I, [2013-03-13T18:24:56.885140 #18793]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
18:24:56 web.1  | I, [2013-03-13T18:24:56.885680 #18793]  INFO -- : master process ready
18:24:56 web.1  | I, [2013-03-13T18:24:56.886145 #18795]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=18795
18:24:56 web.1  | I, [2013-03-13T18:24:56.886272 #18795]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
18:24:57 web.1  | I, [2013-03-13T18:24:57.647574 #18795]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
```

Press Ctrl-C to exit and you can deploy your changes to Heroku:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "use unicorn via procfile"
$ git push heroku master
```

Check ps, you’ll see the web process uses your new command specifying Unicorn as the web server

```
$ heroku ps
=== web (1X): `bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb`
web.1: starting 2014/04/17 12:55:33 (~ 1s ago)
```

At this point you can follow the normal procedure to get your app on heroku

`git init
git add -A
git commit -m "initial commit"`

get things set up on github....then

`heroku create
git push heroku master`

Migrate the database on Heroku

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

make sure the app is set to run

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

open the app

```
heroku open
```